# KeyEvent doesn't detect any keys C#

Tags: c#, keyevent

I'm currently stumped. I can't seem to get the KeyEvent to work. Simple code like this just won't respond to the key I'm pressing. I've tried KeyDown and KeyPress. No errors while compiling... what is causing this?? It will just let me enter the E key without prompting the MEssage box.

```
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("E");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to debug this yourself. Is the code being executed? If yes, what is the value of `e.KeyCode`? If not, why is the event handler not being attached?

Comment: Maybe you should do MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.toString()); and see the output ,because i think you're missing the KeyCode or You're Keyboard is not a standard one.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be using the [PreviewKeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx), for example, instead of the standard key events, as sometimes these events are blocked an not bubbled up through the control.

Comment: @gmajor, if this was the answer, instead of saying "thanks", accept the answer with the check left to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the Form KeyPreview property  to true where textbox1 is located.